# Passing a string to AJAX/Json

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

```
function s() {
    data = "192,273,182,347,13,34,52,2524";
    var jsondata = $.toJSON(data);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.aspx/s",
        data: jsondata,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "text json",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type",
                         "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        },
        success: function (msg) {
            if (msg.d == "OK") {
                //WIN!
            }
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            if (typeof (errorThown) != "undefined")
                alert("ERROR: SaveWidgetSettings() " + textStatus + '\n' + errorThrown);
            else {
                var errdetail = eval("(" + XMLHttpRequest.responseText + ")");
                alert("ERROR: SaveWidgetSettings() " + textStatus + '\n' + errdetail.Message);
            }
        }

    });
```

I debugged the issue to:

```
cannot convert object of type 'system.string' to type 'system.collections.generic.idictionary 2 system.string system.object '
```

are the commas messing up the string?

Comment: your data is a string, not an array, therefore it probably doesn't get converted to the json you expect it to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to wrap the value in an object before serializing so ASP.NET knows what the value is called:

```
data = { csv: "192,273,182,347,13,34,52,2524" };
```

ASP.NET often uses key names to determine which argument to assign a value to (assuming `WebMethod` with the URL being `index.aspx/s`):

```
[WebMethod]
public static object s(string csv) ...
```

Also, if the goal is a collection, `data` can also be an `Array`:

```
data = { ids: [192, 273, 182, 347, 13, 34, 52, 2524] };

// then...
[WebMethod]
public static object s(IEnumerable<int> ids) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data = "192,273,182,347,13,34,52,2524";
var jsondata = $.toJSON(data);
```

http://www.jquerysdk.com/api/jQuery.toJSON

It takes an object argument, not a string.